# Problem removing the last element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

N.B. I am a complete JavaScript beginner.

My assignment is to create an empty array and assign it to a variable. Then, using a for loop, place the numbers 0 to 5 into the array. Then I need to remove the last number in the array and console.log the result.
Any thoughts on why `.pop()` isn't working? It works when I use it on an array that I construct without a `for` loop. Thanks.

```js
var numberList = new Array();
for (let numberList = 0; numberList < 6 ; numberList++)
console.log(numberList);
numberList.pop();
console.log(numberList);
```

Comment: Do you want to call pop at each for loop iteration?  If so, then you are missing curly braces around the statements that should be part of the loop. If not, then you need to show how are you creating the array, because the code you have shown does not do that.

Comment: I edited my post to address your question.

Comment: the problem is your for loop. Since you're using the same name of the variable on the loop, your overwriting it instead of inserting items on the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are not inserting items on your array, you're just reassigning the value of `numberList`

You can try something like that instead:

```js
var numberList = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
  numberList.push(i);
}
console.log(numberList);
numberList.pop();
console.log(numberList);
```

So this way you're pushing the value of `i` into your array, then removing the last one in te end.

Answer (score 1):

You're not pushing anything into the array. Right now, all you do is writing to the console. You need to use Array.push(). Also, you overwrite the numberList array with an integer in your for loop.

```js
var numberList = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
  numberList.push(i);
}

console.log(numberList);
numberList.pop();
console.log(numberList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not add any elements to the array. Use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to do so.

```js
let numberList = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) numberList.push(i);
console.log(...numberList);
numberList.pop();
console.log(...numberList);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in the code.

```
var numberList = new Array();
for (let index= 0; index< 6 ; index++){
    numberList.push(index);
}
console.log(numberList);
numberList.pop();
console.log(numberList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
array.pop();
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the assignment specifically wants a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`array.splice(-1)`

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)